# Exiting Immersive Mode Issue

Tags: android, xamarin

I wrote the following code to enter an activity to the immersive mode.

```
decorView = Window.DecorView;
var uiOptions = (int)decorView.SystemUiVisibility;
var newUiOptions = (int)uiOptions;
newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LowProfile;
newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Immersive;  
newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
decorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)newUiOptions;
```

This works perfectly and I get a perfect immersive mode.

Now the issue is, when I use the following code to exit the immersive mode, It exits the immersive mode but turns my status bar and navigation bar to white.

**BEFORE IMMERSIVE MODE:**

[image]

Status bar and Navigation are light

**AFTER EXITING IMMERSIVE MODE:**

[image]

To Exit immersive mode I am using the following code

```
decorView = Window.DecorView;
decorView.SystemUiVisibility = StatusBarVisibility.Visible;
```

I tried few other things, such as the following

[How to completely exit from Immersive full screen mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667002/how-to-completely-exit-from-immersive-full-screen-mode)

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive

They work but all with white status bar and navigation bar.

In Addition, yes I am using the `LightStatusBar` and `LightNavigationBar` but even setting that when exiting the immersive mode does not work such as

```
decorView = Window.DecorView;
var uiOptions = (int)decorView.SystemUiVisibility;
var newUiOptions = (int)uiOptions;
newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LightNavigationBar;
newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LightStatusBar;
decorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)newUiOptions;
```

Anything I do, I just can't get the status bar and navigation bar back to normal after exiting the immersive mode

Any idea on this?

**STYLES.XML**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>    
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#ffffff</item>    
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="CustomActionBarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">    
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/NoTitleText</item>
  </style>

  <style name="NoTitleText">
    <item name="android:textSize">0sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00000000</item>
  </style>
```

Cheers

Comment: Hello, could you please provide a demo for your question? I can't reproduce your problem, [it](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive) works well on my phone.

Comment: Hi, I found this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660224/status-bar-is-white-when-entering-immersive-full-screen-mode), but I also can't reproduce his question, he has provided an answer for his question, maybe it will help you. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428700/status-bar-turns-white-and-does-not-show-content-behind-it) is about the white color problem.

Comment: Hi Joe, I will create a demo app and will see if I can re-create the issue. I also updated the post to include my `styles.xml` as i think there is something in it causing the issue

Comment: Hi, so your application's min version is 27?

Comment: Hi Joe, my application minimum version is API 21 (lollipop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this might help someone, I found the solution after looking at this https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/AdvancedImmersiveMode/ So basically, fully exit the immersive mode you need to set same UI options but with different values such as

**Enter immersive mode**

```
 decorView = Window.DecorView;
                var uiOptions = (int)decorView.SystemUiVisibility;
                var newUiOptions = (int)uiOptions;
                newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LowProfile;
                newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
                newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
                newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Immersive;
                // This option will make bars disappear by themselves
                newUiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
                decorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)newUiOptions;
```

**Exit immersive mode**

```
decorView = Window.DecorView;
                var uiOptions = (int)decorView.SystemUiVisibility;
                var newUiOptions = (int)uiOptions;
                newUiOptions &= ~(int)SystemUiFlags.LowProfile;
                newUiOptions &= ~(int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
                newUiOptions &= ~(int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
                newUiOptions &= ~(int)SystemUiFlags.Immersive;                
                newUiOptions &= ~(int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
                decorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)newUiOptions;
```

So basically the same options but using `&` along with `~` instead of `OR`

I hope this helps someone - The same code in the link is great to get more info on it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `styles.xml` file, change this:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">#ffffff</item>
```

to this:

```
 <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```